# Stepping through KML Files with DDMS

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mapview

Successfully loaded a KML file into the DDMS Emulator Tab, which shows up as a series of Latitude and Longitude coordinates in the Location Controls window. Is there a way to step through each Placemark, vs. having the entire series play automatically? There are forward and back buttons on the Location Controls window, but no documentation on what they mean. I tried them both, but no Placemark coordinates are highlighted, so I don't know which Placemark is currently the focus. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.... define KML files with timestamps. This way, you can linger on a Placemark for as long as you would like before moving on to the next Placemark. It's a kluge, but those buttons on the Location Controls window don't seem to do anything.